How to draw VWAP line at a certain period of time every day in pinescript on Tradingview?
I'm trying to draw VWAP line at a certain period of time every day in pinescript on Tradingview, but script draws it only at current day and doesn't in the past.
Script i use.
Could you help me to change it pls?
indicator("VWAP (10:00 - 15:30)", overlay=true)

calc_vwap_in_session(start_hour, start_minute, end_hour, end_minute) =>
    var float cum_price_volume = na
    var float cum_volume = na
    if (na(cum_price_volume))
        cum_price_volume := 0.0
        cum_volume := 0.0
    start_time = timestamp("GMT+3", year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), start_hour, start_minute)
    end_time = timestamp("GMT+3", year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), end_hour, end_minute)
    

    if (time >= start_time and time <= end_time)
        cum_price_volume += (high + low + close) / 3 * volume
        cum_volume += volume
    vwap = cum_price_volume / cum_volume
    vwap

plot(calc_vwap_in_session(10, 0, 15, 30), color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="VWAP (10:00 - 15:30)")````

